# Can I tail -f a log and only print certain lines matching some text?

Tags: bash, grep

I'd like to tail a log, find some text and only output the the line found plus the next line, is it possible?

```
THE QUICK 
BROWN FOX 
JUMPED OVER
THE LAZY 
DOG'S BACK
```

Something like:
tail -f | grep BROWN FOX

output would be:

```
BROWN FOX 
JUMPED OVER
```

Comment: With GNU grep I suggest: `man grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tail -<num1> filename.log | grep "search_string" -A num2
```

Example
file: a.log

```
10 20
10 12
11 14
```

```
tail -2 a.log | grep "10" -A 1 # tail -2 indicates two lines from the end of the file
```

Output

```
10 12
11 14
```

Grep options
Use `-n` option in grep to print line number
Use `-C num` option to get leading and trailing context(adjacent lines to the matching one)
Use `-A num` option to get trailing num of lines
Use `-B num` option to get leading num of lines

Answer (score 3):

```
 tail -f log_file_name | grep --line-buffered -A1 BROWN FOX
```

`--line-buffered` causes grep to respond more promptly to the piped input (very useful if the log file grows slowly)

`-A1` asks it to also display one line after each match.